# Set value of DataTemplate Generated controls without binding

Tags: wpf

I'm testing an implementation of an application I need to write in WPF (.NET 4.6.2). The application will have a list of messages. When a message from the list is selected, the details of that message will be presented in a separate area. The messages can be of different types, so the format of the details section will vary. Pretty straight forward master-detail layout stuff.

The unfortunate part is that due to the middleware we're using, the DLL that contains the definitions for the message classes defines fields, not properties, for the members of the classes. My challenge is to update the details section of the UI without being able to rely on binding.

To test this out, I've written an application that has a `ListBox` and `ContentControl`, for displaying the selected message details. I have a simple `Message` class, that has an `Id` property. For the UI, I've created two `DataTemplate`s that can be selected from to display the message details, depending on whether the current `Message` has an `Id` value of 0 or not.

The XAML for the layout is:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestGui"
        x:Name="window" x:Class="TestGui.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MessageDetailSelector x:Key="MessageDetailSelector" />
        <local:MessageList x:Key="MessagesList">
            <local:Message/>
            <local:Message Id="1"/>
            <local:Message Id="2"/>
        </local:MessageList>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ZeroDetailTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label>Zero Detail: </Label>
                <Label x:Name="DetailLabel" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label>Detail:</Label>
                <Label x:Name="DetailLabel" "/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MessagesList}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Id}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <local:CustomContentControl x:Name="DetailControl" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MessageDetailSelector}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

...and the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestGui
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        // Can be used to programmaticaly set DataTemplate:
        //  - add SelectionChanged="MessageSelectionChanged to <ListBox> in XAML
        //  - comment out ContentTemplateSelector from <local:CustomContentControl>
        private void MessageSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems[0] is Message msg)
            {
                DetailControl.ContentTemplate = msg.Id == 0 ?
                    FindResource("ZeroDetailTemplate") as DataTemplate :
                    FindResource("DetailTemplate") as DataTemplate;

                DetailControl.Content = msg;
            }
            else
            {
                DetailControl.ContentTemplate = null;
            }
        }
    }

    class CustomContentControl : ContentControl
    {
        protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
        {
            base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

            ApplyTemplate();
            var cp = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0) as ContentPresenter;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(cp != null);

            DataTemplate dt = cp.ContentTemplate;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dt.FindName("DetailLabel", this);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"OnContentChanged: Cannot find DetailLabel\n{e.Message}");
                    }
                }));
        }

        protected override void OnContentTemplateChanged(DataTemplate oldContentTemplate, DataTemplate newContentTemplate)
        {
            base.OnContentTemplateChanged(oldContentTemplate, newContentTemplate);

            ApplyTemplate();
            var cp = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0) as ContentPresenter;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(cp != null);

            DataTemplate dt = cp.ContentTemplate;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dt.FindName("DetailLabel", this);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"OnContentTemplateChanged: Cannot find DetailLabel\n{e.Message}");
                    }
                }));
        }
    }

    class Message
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    class MessageList : ObservableCollection<Message> { }

    class MessageDetailSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (container is FrameworkElement element && item is Message message)
            {
                if (message.Id == 0)
                {
                    return element.FindResource("ZeroDetailTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                }
                else
                {
                    return element.FindResource("DetailTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

For the most part, it works as expected. I can select one of the messages from the `ListBox`, and the correct template is displayed depending on the id. However, I now need to be able to manually update the values of the controls in the `DataTemplate`.

I created the `CustomContentControl` class so I could override the methods of the `ContentControl` and try to figure out where I can intercept the template to update it. According to [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements), I should be able to call `FindName` on the `ContentPresenter`.

As implemented in this example, using the `MessageDetailSelector` to automatically select the template, the `OnContentChanged` method is being called. However, this is causing an exception because the `ContentTemplate` reference is `null` in this line:

```
DataTemplate dt = cp.ContentTemplate;
```

I tried removing the `ContentTemplateSelector` attribute from the `<local:CustomContentControl>` element, and setting `SelectionChanged` attribute of the `ListBox` to my `MessageSelectionChanged` method. That causes an `InvalidOperationException`, which lead me to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679648/why-would-this-contenttemplate-findname-throw-an-invalidoperationexception-on).

I've tried calling `ApplyTemplate` (which is returning `false` btw), as well as using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, but I'm still getting the same exception.

Any ideas on what I can do get a hold of the `DataTemplate` controls properly, or even thoughts on another method for updating the controls without binding would be appreciated.

Comment: Just an idea, but instead of dealing with DataTemplates, you may write a Binding Converter (for the SelectedItem Binding) that returns the complete UI element that visualizes an item.

Comment: Or you write a Binding Converter that returns a wrapper class with properties that makes it usable as Binding source object. DataTemplates aren't particular useful without the possibility to data bind their elements.

Comment: @Clemens - I have thought about writing wrapper classes. Unfortunately, there are more than a few message classes, and they're pretty complex and potentially fluid until the design is fully locked down. I dreamed of a way to dynamically generate the wrappers, but I haven't motivated myself enough to go down that path yet :). I will look into your suggestion on Binding Coverters in the meantime.